# Bucket search - facets filter limited to 10 results

Tags: contact-facets, buckets, search-facet

Been digging around how to get more than 10 results for each facet filter and can't find any setting to do so - also tried to dotpeek without any luck.

[image]

Does anyone came across with this issue or know a solution for this? I can see the following ajax being made:

- /sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx

Which returns always a maximum of 10 as per below:
[image]

Comment: Are you specifically in Experience Analytics? The normal search results API does not have a limit. From the screen shots, it looks like you are in EA.

Comment: Not in EA. Simple bucket search through content editor with some custom facets.

Comment: The Authors facet shows more than 10 results in SC 9.0

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Azure Search - However, just found out it is a limitation with Azure search:

https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/rest/api/searchservice/Search-Documents?redirectedfrom=MSDN

which defaults to 10.